# Displaying all keys value pair of array in nested json javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data from a URL and c am consuming it using jQuery ajax method.

Now as the JSON code below shows I have a DATA array containing objects in my JSON, now if I access `FirstName` using `resp.DATA[0].FirstName`, I am able to get it, but now I have to display all the key value pairs in DATA array and **i don't know the key name i.e. I have to show every key and value.**
There are two customers on data.

How can I do it either using JavaScript or jQuery?

**JSON DATA:**

```
    {
    "ERROR": [],
    "DATA": [{
        "CustomerID": "124",
        "BranchID": "12",
        "FirstName": "sandeep",
        "LastName": "b",
        "EmailID": "gggg@gmail.com",
        "Sex": "Male",
        "Landline": "",
        "AlternateNumber": "",
        "Password": "5735c2801",
        "USERVARCHAR_2": ""
    }],
    "META": {
        "totalPages": "1",
    }
}
```

**I have to display Key and value of each customer data in the form `KEY:VALUE`,** so please suggest me how to loop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys(object_name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to fetch all the keys of a Object.

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
for(var cust of resp.DATA){ // To iterate a array

  for(var key in cust){ // To iterate a object ennumerable properties
  
     console.log("Key is: "+key+" and Value is: "+cust[key]);
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: your code worked like charm!
i have a doubt what if my code has two customers like

{
    "ERROR": [],
    "DATA": [{
        "CustomerID": "124",
        "BranchID": "12",
        "FirstName": "sandeep",
        "LastName": "b",
        "EmailID": "gggg@gmail.com",
    },{
        "CustomerID": "124",
        "BranchID": "12",
        "FirstName": "sandeep",
        "LastName": "b",
        "EmailID": "gggg@gmail.com",
    }],
    "META": {
        "totalPages": "1",
    }
}

Will this work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the for loop to iterate over javascript array literal

```
for (var key in resp.DATA) {

    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!resp.DATA.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var objct = resp.DATA[key];
    for (var prop in objct) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if(!objct.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        // your code
        alert("The key is  "+prop + "and the value is " + objct[prop]);
    }
}
```

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: Your code worked. Thanks!
Can u  explain this code or provide link to study especially what the both if loops and for loops are doing.

Comment: I ma not comparing but another answer from void also worked, are there any benifits of using !resp.DATA.hasOwnProperty .
Please vote my question someone has marked it as dublicate.

Comment: @SandeepBiradar hasOwnproperty is saver but itterating over an array using for in is not save and will list itterable members of Array.prototype. you can use array.forEach or a counter. I find mdn a good source for information. You can Google "mdn array prototype" or "mdn hasOwnproperty"

Answer (score 0):

Loop in to your array like this using `.each()`

```
 $.each(your_array, function(key, value) {
    alert('Array Key is: '+ key + ' \n Array Key value is: ' + value);
    });
```

> [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for
>   each matched element.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
$(resp.DATA[0]).each(function(key, value){
    // your code
});
```