# loop through json javascript

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I got a json which looks like something like this :

```
var json = {
  "stock1" : {
    "positions" : [{
      "date": "29/02/2016",
      "price": 15,
      "type": "short"
     }]
   },
  "stock2" : {
    "positions" : [{
      "date": "29/02/2016",
      "price": 20,
      "type": "long"
     }]
   }
};
```

For the moment I have something like that :

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  ;
  }
</script>
  <div id = "short">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
      short
    </button>
  </div>
```

My json is actually bigger than this example. I'd like to loop through it to get only the positions who are "short" and print them.
What is the best way to do that using only javascript ?

EDIT :

This is my new code but I still can't access to short or long position :

```
var stocks = [];
var longOnMarket = [];
var shortOnMarket = [];
var typeOfPosition = [];
var lolz = [];
for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item  = json[key];
        lolz.push(JSON.stringify(item));
        stocks.push(key);
        var json2 = json[item];
        for (var key2 in json2) {
            if (json2.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
            var longOrShort = json2[key2].positions;
            typeOfPosition.push(JSON.stringify(longOrShort));
          }
        }
    }
}
alert(stocks);
alert(lolz);
alert(typeOfPosition);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying all keys value pair of array in nested json javascrpit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124166/displaying-all-keys-value-pair-of-array-in-nested-json-javascrpit)

Answer (score 0):

You should simple iterate through your object keys

```
var result = [];
for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item  = json[key];
        item.positions = item.positions.filter(function(el) { return el.type == 'short' });
        result.push(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `positions` is an array.

Comment: @suvroc this will throw an error of undefiend as you are trying to fetch out the data of an array with key as like an Object so

Comment: I'm not really familiar with "positions.filter", why is this usefull ?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara that is exactly my problem, all I'm getting is "undefined" when I try to catch some type of position

Comment: @zardlemalefique check https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter @@HimeshAadeshara I don't really see where it might be the problem with undefined

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
var json = {
  "stock1" : {
    "positions" : [{
      "date": "29/02/2016",
      "price": 15,
      "type": "short"
     }]
   },
  "stock2" : {
    "positions" : [{
      "date": "29/02/2016",
      "price": 20,
      "type": "long"
     }]
   }
};

var object = JSON.parse(json);
for (var key in object) {
//Do your stuff

}
```

Comment: Why do I have to use JSON.parse ?

Comment: To convert into proper JSON Form. More info is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This solution looks for the array of `positions` and returns the object if some `short` is found.

```js
var object = { "stock1": { "positions": [{ "date": "29/02/2016", "price": 15, "type": "short" }] }, "stock2": { "positions": [{ "date": "29/02/2016", "price": 20, "type": "long" }] } },
    short = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    if (object[k].positions.some(function (a) { return a.type === 'short' })) {
        short[k] = object[k];
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(short, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my try please check it out

```
var i,
shortTypePositionsArray = [],
shortTypeWholeObject = {};
$.each(json,function(key,value){ 
    if(Object.keys(value) == "positions"){  
        for(i = 0;i<value.positions.length;i++){
           if(value.positions[i].type == 'short')
           {
              shortTypePositionsArray.push(value.positions[i]);
              shortTypeWholeObject[key] = value;
           }
        }
    }
});
console.log(shortTypePositionsArray);
console.log(shortTypeWholeObject);
```